# Android BLE receive advertisement data in none connectable mode

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

In Android, I try to receive BLE advertisement data in ** non-connectable** mode.

**BLE Beacon** is **Broadcasting** packets in none connectable mode.

The Same tool is `Packet Sniffer` windows application using '**ADV_NON_CONN_IND**' flag

Now I get a list of devices, How I can read broadcasting packets?

[image]

About the above picture, I need to have access to **AdvData** part.

Comment: But in your picture it says ADV_IND and not ADV_NON_CONN_IND?

Comment: it should be exactly "ADV_NON_CONN_IND", I'll change this picture. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just perform a BLE scan. It shouldn't matter if the advertising type is connectable or not.

Comment: not possible, nRF Connect cannot connect to the Bluetooth device too

Comment: nRFConnect will detect non connectable advertisements, but can of course not connect to such a device